# what should I name my KeyAlias in Flutter app exporting?

Tags: android, flutter

I am currently exporting an app with flutter I have generated a keytool named key.jks as suggested on the dev site. In key.properties file they show to put **keyAlias=key** now should I also name the same or should I change it (can I change the name actually?) what should I give the name of keyAlias?

Comment: You can give it any name you want. I would suggest something descriptive, so you know what the key is for, and easy to remember.

Comment: like anything? even the name of my app?

Comment: Yes the alias is just the identifier for a specific key in your key store. Name it as you wish, and access it by said alias.

Comment: okay it helped a lot

Comment: @Lee3 you said I can give anything to the alias property but I saw that I can only give the alias name "key" which I gave the generator while generating the keystore so does it mean I have to use the alias name "key" in all of my apps? or can I make sign multiple alias for one keystore?

Comment: A single keystore can contain multiple aliases that refer to different keys.